# Mocking a datacontext for an object that has a dependency

Tags: unit-testing, asp.net-mvc-2, moq, ninject, ninject-2

I'm writing some unit tests in my project and I have a datacontext dependency on the controller containing the methods I'd like to test.

I'm using Ninject to inject the dependency and Moq to create my mock datacontext. My DI makes use of an interface `IDataContext` which my dbml impliments and is used through out the injection process.

In my unit test I'm creating my mock datacontext as follows:

```
var mock = new Mock<IDataContext>();
var myController = new MyController(mock.Object);
```

This throws a `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.` exception on the second line whilst executing the datacontexts constructor.

I'm clearly missing a fundamental piece in setting this up however most of the Moq examples I've seen involve some kind of test against the mocked object using `Setup()`.

Am I going about this the right way? Should I be creating a mock of my `IDataContext` interface or something else?

Comment: Can you show the call stack for the exception?

Comment: Also, what is going on in the constructor for MyController?

If I had to hazard a guess at this point, you're missing a setup on the mock object that should return something being used in the constructor.

Comment: Thanks for the comments guys. I was just about to reply before melaos posted the answer I was looking for. Thanks again for taking the time to comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

haha,
the answer came while i was reading through [emad's blog on unit testing in ASP.Net MVC.](http://www.emadibrahim.com/2008/04/04/unit-test-linq-to-sql-in-aspnet-mvc-with-moq/)

I'm guessing that you didn't add the connection string to the app.config of your test project right? :)

And that's the database dependency way because you're still not mocking the database end.
So if you want to do that, you need to google up for some codes, there are a few ways to do that.

i find these few references below to be quite useful, but since i don't really have a need to mock the database end, i'm just using my test DB server for now.

[link](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/aviwortzel/archive/2008/03/25/testing-linq-to-sql-with-mock-object-a-complete-solution.aspx)

Comment: Thanks melaos! Adding an app.config to my tests project and placing my connection string code in there works a treat. Excellent!